# Is the Firebase database for use on a normal HTML website?

Tags: html, database, firebase, web

I come from the iOS world and am familiar with Firebase, but now too to make a website with Firebase features e.g. data retrieval and account management, and would like to know if I can use Firebase for a normal website ?

I assume so, but would it be the best course of action ?

My needs are not too heavy at present, but in time user account could number in the thousands, with a lot of daily traffic.

I will need to learn HTML, but what else will I need to make a decent front end web experience these days ?

Comment: Firebase supports multiple platforms including iOS and web. The usage and functionally is same except you use different SDKs. I would recommend checking out [Add Firebase to your Javascript project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) to get started.

Comment: Some more good starting points: https://firebase.google.com/learn/pathways/firebase-web, https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-get-to-know-web and https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web

Answer (score 1):

HTML (**H**ypertext **M**arkup **L**anguage) is a markup language that will let you describe the structure of the content of your website. However it is not a programming language that can communicate with Firebase.

To use Firebase services from the browser (a "normal" webiste), you need to use javascript. Specifically you can use the [Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup). Once configured, the SDK provides an interface to acces Firebase services, like [the real time database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start).

It is important to note that a browser is a *public* client that cannot hold secrets. Therefore, if you want to perform actions that should not be directly available to your end users, you need to use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) server-side. In this case you authenticate your server using a service account.

Comment: So I need to learn Javascript.

Comment: Yes ! There is a ton on material on the subject. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/) is a great reference, but might be a bit frightening at first. For beginners, I always hear a great deal about [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news) you should give it a try !